# What does -u9999999 in a git diff really mean?

Tags: git, diff

I was wondering how to get git to allways show you the full file in a `git diff`rather than only showing the hunks.

So I first went with the `-W`option but I read that this actually tries to be clever and tries to find the function context of the change. I don't want git to be clever. I want git to be dead simple and only show me the full file with the changes.

So I finally figured out that you can add `-U9999999` and now I am like WTF!? and wonder what kind of crazy hack this is and why it's not documented anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git diff -U9999999` means "do a unified diff and show 9,999,999 lines of context for each hunk." It is documented; `git help diff` shows:

```
       -U<n>, --unified=<n>
           Generate diffs with <n> lines of context instead of the usual
           three. Implies -p.
```

Of course, if you have a file with more than 9,999,999 lines between differing regions, this won't actually show the whole file, but for all practical purposes, it will always show the whole thing.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I didn't thought of `-U` beeing a option on it's own. Stupid me!

Answer (score 2):

From the manual:

```
-U<n>
--unified=<n>
Generate diffs with <n> lines of context instead of the usual three. Implies -p.
```

So you're telling it to display the diff with 9999999 lines of context, which in practice means the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

You're telling git to generated diffs with extra lines of context. Context being lines of code around each change.

If you say

```
git diff -u9999999
```

You're telling git to put 9999999 lines of unchanged code around each change, which should be enough for any code file you create.